# Namespace 'google.maps' has no exported member 'MouseEvent'

Tags: javascript, angular, google-maps-api-3, angular-google-maps

I wanted to integrate Google Maps with my Angular project. In the pilot version, I was just following this link **https://angular-maps.com/guides/getting-started/**. Currently, I am stuck in error:

`node_modules/@agm/core/lib/directives/map.d.ts:232:43 - error TS2694: Namespace 'google.maps' has no exported member 'MouseEvent'`

`232     mapDblClick: EventEmitter<google.maps.MouseEvent>;`

I went to the file location and got this

```
    mapClick: EventEmitter<google.maps.MouseEvent | google.maps.IconMouseEvent>;
    /**
     * This event emitter gets emitted when the user right-clicks on the map (but not when they click
     * on a marker or infoWindow).
     */
    mapRightClick: EventEmitter<google.maps.MouseEvent>;
    /**
     * This event emitter gets emitted when the user double-clicks on the map (but not when they click
     * on a marker or infoWindow).
     */
    mapDblClick: EventEmitter<google.maps.MouseEvent>;
    /**
```

Dependencies:
npm install @agm/core
npm i @types/googlemaps

Comment: Please check out my answer, the solution was just merged now and published, there's no more need for workarounds.

Answer (score 24):

I found, that the workaround mentioned in some of the other answers does not work if you are using `@agm/core`. I came across the same error when updating to Angular 11.

It seems, that Angular 11 does not work properly in combination with `@agm/core 3.0.0-beta.0` (newest version). Try to downgrade `@agm/core` to the previous version `1.1.0`. This worked for me.

```
"dependencies": {
    "@agm/core": "^1.1.0"
}
```

Comment: Downgrading to @agm/core 1.1.0 worked for me, thank you.I was using @agm/core 3.0.0-beta.0 with Angular 9.

Answer (score 14):

It work around solution found on [this github response](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/50253#issuecomment-751532061)

```
"dependencies": {
     "@angular/google-maps": "^11.0.0"
}
```

then add

```
"devDependencies": {
     "@types/googlemaps": "3.39.14"
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Guys the solution is already merged,

https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/pull/50565#issuecomment-759785211

try installing `@types/googlemaps@3.43.2` from `npm`.

Answer (score 5):

Had the same error on my Angular 12 project but it worked after downgrading @types/googlemaps.

```
"dependencies": {
    "@agm/core": "^3.0.0-beta.0",
},
"devDependencies": {
    "@types/googlemaps": "^3.39.12",
}
```

Comment: this helped me solve this issue https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/48574 but not the one from OP

Comment: Thanks @Stephan TP, this worked for me. Phew! few hours of googling and you came as the saviour. Gets into this agm issue time and again when ever there is a version upgrade. Wondering whether its best to switch to Angular's Google Map Component.

Answer (score 5):

I'm adding a new answer with a radical solution.

**TL;DR:**

I got rid of agm/core and replaced it by the ngx-autocomplete package. I also updated my angular to v12 in the process, but that was most likely not necessary. [Ref to article](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-build-an-angular-12-application-with-google-places-autocomplete/).

**Long version:**

Previously, I needed to use 2 packages

- agm/core to get google-map edition that provided onAddressChange in my components so I could get the google place ID, latLng, etc
- angular/google-maps for showing a map with a marker on an address
- those packages need to be version-synchronized with a typescript `@type/googlemaps` package

After looking at various answers I found many things to watch our for

- Version numbers (and presence or absence of "^" is important)
- Having the @type package in dependencies and not devDependencies may help
- Adding "googlemaps" to the compilerOptions.types array in all tsconfig*.json (.app.json, .spec.json, tsconfig.json)

Despite this and trying various configurations, I could not make it work. It seems like I needed, in order to fix all my bugs, both

- @types/googlemaps": >= 3.39.14
- @types/googlemaps": <= 3.39.12

With errors like

> Generic type 'MapHandlerMap' requires 1 type argument(s).

or

> Namespace 'google.maps' has no exported member 'MouseEvent'

My mindset was the following: instead of downgrading version until I find the good one, just bump everything to the latest version (using `ng update` it went rather smoothly), which included all angular modules, and then get rid of incompatible libraries that are not maintained and/or deprecated.

Turns out `agm/core` became the main culprit. Just look at how long it has been stuck at `3.0.0-beta.0`, and the semver patch version `beta.0` is already a big hint that you should not use this package.

After googling a bit, I found out that the `ngx-google-places-autocomplete` package was much more straightforward to implement, and offered a much simpler interface with only one handler to implement (just look at the article I linked in the tl;dr - you can implement it in a few secs). It was also compatible with `angular/google-maps` and the type package without doing anything else.

I mentioned that I upgraded to angular 12, but I believe you do not need to do this, and ngx-google-places-autocomplete can most likely work with anterior angular versions. Just get rid of agm.

Answer (score 4):

I faced the same issue with Angular 11. Here is the combination that worked fine for me (package.json):

```
"dependencies": {
...
    "@agm/core": "^1.1.0",
... 
}
"devDependencies": {
...
"@types/googlemaps": "^3.39.12",
...
}
```

P.S.: Some tutorials recommend to add @google/maps but I did not add that package.

Comment: @agm/core^3.0.0-beta.0 and @types/googlemaps@^3.39.12 also works (for me)..

Answer (score 3):

I had same issue with Angular-Cli 11 and "@agm/core": "^3.0.0-beta.0",
I resolved by adding @types/googlemaps: "3.39.12" to my devDependencies, now it works !

Answer (score 3):

With the latest version, `MouseEvent` is now named `MapMouseEvent`.

Tied with
`"@angular/google-maps": "^13.2.3",`
`"@types/google.maps": "3.47.4"`

be careful tho download [this one](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/google.maps) not to download `@types/googlemaps` without the `*.*`, which is a [deprecated library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/googlemaps)

Answer (score 2):

none of the above worked for me, my angular version is 10 and as per [this](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/50253#issuecomment-752038982) the issue is with compatibility of @angular/googlemaps and @types/googlemaps on which angular team is currently working.

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution and work for me.

I use Angular 10

because `@agm/core support latest angular v.10`

Solution below,

```
npm i @agm/core@^3.0.0-beta.0

npm i @types/googlemaps@3.39.13 --save-dev
```

Full code

```
{
  "name": "web-vacc-care-ng10",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@agm/core": "^3.0.0-beta.0",
    "@angular/animations": "~10.2.4",
    "@angular/common": "~10.2.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "~10.2.4",
    "@angular/core": "~10.2.4",
    "@angular/forms": "~10.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~10.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~10.2.4",
    "@angular/router": "~10.2.4",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1002.3",
    "@angular/cli": "~10.2.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~10.2.4",
    "@types/googlemaps": "^3.39.13",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.5.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~5.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~4.0.2"
  }
}
```

Work for me.

Answer (score -2):

Since upgrading to Angular 11 I started to experience this issue.

The work around is; in your "node_modules/@agm/core/lib/services/" folder, you will need to change MapHandlerMap to MapMouseEvent at a few places (check your terminal log to see where).

Comment: Any change to files in `node_modules` folder will be discarded when you reinstall the package, so this will be just a temp fix.