# Namespace 'google.maps' has no exported member 'MouseEvent'. with installation of @agm/core and @types/google

Tags: angular

when i tried to install @agm/core and @types/google maps iam getting follwing errors

```
node_modules/@angular/google-maps/map-polyline/map-polyline.d.ts:42:45 - error TS2694: Namespace 'google.maps' has no exported member 'MouseEvent'.

42     polylineDragend: Observable<google.maps.MouseEvent>;
                                               ~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@angular/google-maps/map-polyline/map-polyline.d.ts:46:47 - error TS2694: Namespace 'google.maps' has no exported member 'MouseEvent'.

46     polylineDragstart: Observable<google.maps.MouseEvent>;
                                                 ~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@angular/google-maps/map-rectangle/map-rectangle.d.ts:36:44 - error TS2694: Namespace 'google.maps' has no exported member 'MouseEvent'.

36     rectangleClick: Observable<google.maps.MouseEvent>;
                                              ~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@angular/google-maps/map-rectangle/map-rectangle.d.ts:41:47 - error TS2694: Namespace 'google.maps' has no exported member 'MouseEvent'.

41     rectangleDblclick: Observable<google.maps.MouseEvent>;
                                                 ~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@angular/google-maps/map-rectangle/map-rectangle.d.ts:46:43 - error TS2694: Namespace 'google.maps' has no exported member 'MouseEvent'.

46     rectangleDrag: Observable<google.maps.MouseEvent>;
[7m                                             ~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@angular/google-maps/map-rectangle/map-rectangle.d.ts:51:46 - error TS2694: Namespace 'google.maps' has no exported member 'MouseEvent'.

51     rectangleDragend: Observable<google.maps.MouseEvent>;
                                                ~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@angular/google-maps/map-rectangle/map-rectangle.d.ts:56:48 - error TS2694: Namespace 'google.maps' has no exported member 'MouseEvent'.

56     rectangleDragstart: Observable<google.maps.MouseEvent>;
                                                  ~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@angular/google-maps/map-rectangle/map-rectangle.d.ts:61:48 - error TS2694: Namespace 'google.maps' has no exported member 'MouseEvent'.

61     rectangleMousedown: Observable<google.maps.MouseEvent>;
                                                  ~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@angular/google-maps/map-rectangle/map-rectangle.d.ts:66:48 - error TS2694: Namespace 'google.maps' has no exported member 'MouseEvent'.

66     rectangleMousemove: Observable<google.maps.MouseEvent>;
                                                  ~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@angular/google-maps/map-rectangle/map-rectangle.d.ts:71:47 - error TS2694: Namespace 'google.maps' has no exported member 'MouseEvent'.

71     rectangleMouseout: Observable<google.maps.MouseEvent>;
                                                 ~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@angular/google-maps/map-rectangle/map-rectangle.d.ts:76:48 - error TS2694: Namespace 'google.maps' has no exported member 'MouseEvent'.

76     rectangleMouseover: Observable<google.maps.MouseEvent>;
                                                  ~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@angular/google-maps/map-rectangle/map-rectangle.d.ts:81:46 - error TS2694: Namespace 'google.maps' has no exported member 'MouseEvent'.

81     rectangleMouseup: Observable<google.maps.MouseEvent>;
                                                ~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@angular/google-maps/map-rectangle/map-rectangle.d.ts:86:49 - error TS2694: Namespace 'google.maps' has no exported member 'MouseEvent'.

86     rectangleRightclick: Observable<google.maps.MouseEvent>;
                                                   ~~~~~~~~~~
```

How to get rid of this errors

Answer (score 0):

it's lokking like a package error so try to update your packages.

[Namespace 'google.maps' has no exported member 'MouseEvent'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65478922/namespace-google-maps-has-no-exported-member-mouseevent)